# (apache, nodejs) Requesting Node app from PHP

Tags: php, node.js, apache, npm, server

I've took some code from other posts to implement Apache app to request Node app.
Following Node app "works" but I cannot access post parameters which are undefined.

```
//NODE
express = require('express');
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app = express();
port = 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/get_php_data', function (req, res) {
    // php array will be here in this variable
    var data = req.param.data; // I've tried req.body.data;

    var response = String(data)+String((7*data+3*data+1*data) % 3);
    console.log(req); // This seems log req parameter in a loop
    res.send(data);
});

app.listen(port);
```

PHP-part (just POST request with one parameter):

```
echo httpPost('localhost:3000/get_php_data', array('data' => 1));

function httpPost($url,$params)
{
    $postData = http_build_query($params);
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

This setup returns undefined. How to access POST parameters with Node?

Answer (score 0):

Well, answer was simple. In Node script change the 5th line as follows:

```
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run server if they are on same machine you can use php `` which interprets commands line. No need to run http on same machine to reach it.